# Floating div is not working with float or display

Tags: html, css

So I am new to web dev and just trying to get the hang of moving divs around, but when I include any float statements my back vanishes. Take for instance my code below, If you remove the `float: right` my second division reappears. This happens when I try to float any of them, or even try to `display: inline-block` Some one help!! :) Thank you.

I want to note I have tried every float combination I could think of just to see if I was floating them the wrong way.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}


.division1 {
  background-color:blue;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.division2 {
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Practice with divs!</title>
  <link href = "style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "division1"></div>
    <div class = "division2"></div>
</bod1y>
</html>
```

Comment: the `min-width/height` is `0` unless the div has content or an explicit width.

Comment: then why if you run this code do 2, 100px div's appear?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you're saying.

Comment: I only see one blue div when I hit run code snippet...

Comment: That's because the **float:right** is in the code. If you remove that, you will see a second div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}


.division1 {
  background-color:blue;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.division2 {
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Practice with divs!</title>
  <link href = "style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "division1"></div>
    <div class = "division2"></div>
</bod1y>
</html>
```

You'll have to give it a width, because otherwise, it will have a width of 0px and therefore not be displayed. Also, float both div's so they appear next to each other. I hope this is the result you seek to create.

Comment: It is, with some minor issues. Why are they floated so far apart and not right next to each other? Secondly, anytime I ever use min/max height/width, I'll have to re-establish a concrete width/height?

Comment: Because of the "float: right;" - change it to "float: left;", and they will be right next to each other :)

Comment: I'm not seeing any large margin properties so why such a distance between the 2 divs?

Comment: Because of the "float: right;", as I mentioned above. Change it to "float: left;".

Comment: AHHHHHH, I see now, the mental picture is starting to form. Thanks buddy :)

Comment: No problem! Please mark the answer as accepted and give it an upvote if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: Will do, still have 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a border to body, you'll see what is happening. You'll still need to set a width or a min-width (or give it some content) for it to show:

```css
body {
  background-color: grey; 
  border: 3px dotted red;
}

.division1 {
  background-color:blue;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.division2 {
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  /* min-width: 100px; */
  margin-left: 10px;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Practice with divs!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "division1"></div>
    <div class = "division2">x</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you just want to place two equally sized boxes next to each other there are better ways to do that:

```css
body { 
  height: 100px; width: 500px;
  border: 3px dotted red;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.one { width: 300px;  background-color: lightblue; }
.two { flex: 1;       background-color: lightgreen; }
body>div { 
  padding: 1ex;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="one">Fixed width column..  "Sed ut perspiciatis unde
    omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque
    laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo
    inventore </div>
  <div class="two">"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error
  sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get them closer to each other and aligned by placing a container around them and setting a size to that container.

Try out "ems" or pixels for more accuracy.

```css
  

  body {
      background-color: grey;
    }


   body {
  background-color: grey;
}
.container{
  width:35%;
}

.division1 {
  background-color:blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
  float:left;
}

.division2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title> Practice with divs!</title>
      <link href = "style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
    <div class = "division1"></div>
    <div class = "division2"></div>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```